# CSS is not working for ngx-datatable print view

Tags: css, angular

I am trying show the ngx-datatable data on print view, But Table data CSS is not working properly.So How to resolve this issue.

app.component.css:

```
 @media print {
  :host ::ng-deep .datatable-body-cell {
    padding: 10px !important;
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }

  :host ::ng-deep .datatable-body-cell-label {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }

  :host ::ng-deep .datatable-header-cell {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
 printView() {
    var tblData = document.getElementById("tblData");
    var win = window.open("", "", "height=700,width=700");
    win.document.write(tblData.outerHTML);
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-z1v7vy?file=app%2Fapp.component.scss

Comment: when css not working

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: On Print View

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: You have any solution?

Comment: https://angular-ngx-datatable-hcivje.stackblitz.io/ checkout this. is this working for you ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: Css working but table not visible properly..I think table width issue?

Comment: https://angular-ngx-datatable-hcivje.stackblitz.io/ check this out now its working or not ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: Not Working Properly

Comment: whats not working ? @Sansara

Comment: @GaurangDhorda: Actually in the print view should contain all the data only, But in you code table data pagination also coming on the print page. So How to resolve it? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatable-38wwwa?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232053/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-sansara).

Comment: I have an almost exact same question @Sansara, when using control + p to print my page, the :host ::ng-deep .datatable-row-odd {
        background-color: #eee;
    } style disapears. Did you learn anything?